# Custom Group model for Django Guardian

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-guardian

Django guardian requires `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group` to assign row-level permission to a group. I have my own group model that is NOT an instance of `Group`. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I think guardian is very tightly tied to the django `auth` I doubt there will be an easy workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: [django-guardian: direct-foreign-keys](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/performance.html#direct-foreign-keys)
But you have to copy a lots of classes into your own code section and replace the group parts.